# Наследование от std::vector

Tags: c++, наследование, virtual, деструктор

Подробно изучая механизм наследования в C++ наткнулся на такую фразу [деструктор полиморфного базового класса должен объявляться виртуальным](http://cpp-reference.ru/articles/virtual-destructor/). Легально ли наследоваться от std::vector, если его деструктор объявлен без `virtual`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Легально. Виртуальный деструктор в базовом классе при наследовании нужен только когда владение объектом будет осуществляться через указатель на базовый класс. Кроме того, `std::vector` не является полиморфным классом.

Comment: Что-то запутался - а можно наследовать класс с невртуальным деструктором, но в своем классе сделать его виртуальным - для будущих наследований?

Comment: @Mikhailo Можно, но деструктор в самом базовом классе при этом так и останется не виртуальным.

Comment: А в последующих - виртуальный? А с функциями-членами такой фокус получится?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class A {
public:
    A() { cout << "A()" << endl; }
    ~A() { cout << "~A()" << endl; }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B() { cout << "B()" << endl; }
    ~B() { cout << "~B()" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод

```
A()
B()
~B()
~A()
```

Теперь с указателями

```
int main()
{
    A * pA = new B;
    delete pA;
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод

```
A()
B()
~A()
```

Т.о. само по себе наследование от класса с невиртуальным деструктором вполне легально, но при работе с динамическими объектами оно порождает ошибку с пропуском вызова полиморфного деструктора нужного класса